# SQLAlchemy: how can I order a table by a column permanently?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm not sure if this has been answered before, I didn't get anything on a quick search.

My table is built in a random order, but thereafter it is modified very rarely. I do frequent selects from the table and in each select I need to order the query by the same column. Now is there a way to sort a table permanently by a column so that it does not need to be done again for each select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an index sorted by the column you want. The data will be presorted according to that index.

Comment: My tables are indexed, I didn't know SQLAlchemy does that. I'm using SQLite, according to knitti's answer would that affect it?

Comment: That's not a sqlalchemy feature, it's a feature of your RDBMS. You can specify implicit ordering of a table using indexes.

Comment: Check this https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html (go to the sorting section) as to how the query planner works on sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can have only one place where you define it, and re-use that for 
every query:

```
def base_query(session, what_for):
    return session.query(what_for).order_by(what_for.rank_or_whatever)
```

Expand that as needed, then for all but very complex queries you can use that like so:

```
some_query = base_query(session(), Employee).filter(Employee.feet > 3)
```

The resulting query will be ordered by `Employee.rank_or_whatever`. If you are always querying for the same, You won't habve to use it as argument, of course.

EDIT: If you could somehow define a "permanent" order on your table which is observed by the engine without being issued an `ORDER BY` I'd think this would be an implementation feature specific to which RDBMS you use, and just convenience. *Internally* it makes for a DBMS no sense to being coerced how to store the data, since retrieving this data in a specific order is easily *and* efficiently accomplished by using an `INDEX` - forcing a specific order would probably decrease overall performance.

Comment: I'm more concerned with the time wasted by needing to do a fresh sort each time than re-writing order_by